# How to synchronize property updates to a single domain instance?

Tags: orm, persistence

I am looking for ideas to synchronize updates to a single instance of a persisted object.

A simple domain object:

```
public class Employee {
     long id;
     String phone;
     String address;
}
```

Suppose two UI instances pull up Employee(1) where id=1.  The first client edits the phone property of Employee(1); the second client edits the address property of Employee(1).  When they submit their changes, both need to be persisted.

A possible solution would be to create an update function for each property:

```
public void updatePhone(Employee employee) {
     // right now I am synchronizing _employeeUpdateLock
     // synchronize instance of Employee won't work
     synchronized( something ) {
          // update phone
     }
}
// a similar function for address
```

This approach unfortunately doesn't scale well.  The API needs to constantly aligns itself to the properties.  Note that

```
public void update(Employee employee) { ... }
```

won't work because the function can't tell which property the client intends to change, unless a copy of the original object can be pulled up within the update function.

Hibernate provides a mechanism to lock a row to the database.  This doesn't scale well either.

Perhaps the solution depends on the frequency a row's expected to be modified.  For low frequency modifications, synchronized and locks are fine.  For high frequency modifications, a copy of the row at the time of retrieval can be used to figure out the updated properties.

I am hoping to find a better paradigm to solve this problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your intended architecture. Several clients are to share one instance of the same data object? How is that even possible - short of using some kind of remote object model (which is considered a bad thing nowadays)?

Comment: They are not sharing one instance of an object, but rather one row to a database.

Comment: Alright, I should take up the habit of reading the whole post before drawing conclusions. ;-)
As for your problem, this basically sounds like a question of optimistic vs. pessimistic concurrency. The Hibernate documentation sums it up nicely here (along with approaches supported by Hibernate, obviously): http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic